# Swift 4 Generic where clause Error

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to write the following function

```
func take<C: Collection where C.Iterator.Element Int>(_ value: C) {
   print(value.first)
}
```

But I Keep getting a compiler error:

```
'where' clause next to generic parameters is obsolete, must be written following the declaration's type
```

Comment: Just click on the "Fix" button that Xcode presents ...

Comment: That was not the fix.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like you are not very familiar with the syntax of generic constraints. It should be written like this:

```
func take<C: Collection>(_ value: C) where C.Iterator.Element == Int {
    print(value.first)
}
```

Here the error message *is* a bit confusing. Basically it is asking you to write the constraint just before the `{`.